# Super noobish prolog arithmetic

Tags: math, compiler-errors, prolog

Very new to prolog. For a program I would like to say A1 = X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 to add up to 16. Also, I want to say that X1 must = 1. Note X1 to Xn are all permuted numbers from 1-9. 
I wrote the code the following way

```
 A1 is (X1 is 1) + X2 + X3 + X4, A1 =:= 16.
```

From this I get the compiler error Arithmetic: `_7206 is 6' is not a function

it's the same if I replace the 'is' in (X1 is 1) with =, or =:=

P.S A preferred answer would be great if the formatting was kept the same.

Comment: The construct `A1 is (X1 is 1)...` doesn't have a valid semantic meaning in Prolog for expressions. `X1 is 1` only succeeds or fails when evaluated. It doesn't "return" a value.

Comment: You need separate statements: `X1 = 1, A1 is X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, ...`.

Comment: Understood. Did that thanks